# How to get Google streetview latlng from panoid?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

I have a Google Streetview **panoid** list, i want to find out their locations(latlng), How do i make it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Use the method [getPanoramaById()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewService) of the StreetViewService to retrieve the panoramaData. The response will contain a [location](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#StreetViewLocation)-property with data related to the location, e.g. the `latLng`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem as the original poster.  Using the API works, but isn't the best if you're just looking to convert panoIDs to lat/lon's.  The following python code works much better for this task: https://code.google.com/p/adqmisc/source/browse/trunk/streetview/StreetView.py